# Problem with how the data is represented in graphs

Tags: data-visualisation, diagram

What are the problems with how the data is represented in the following graphs? What alternative plotting method can be used to better convey the information?

[image]

For the ten states graph, I think it may be better to show the number of homeless rather than rate, as a similar rate can be from very different numbers.

[image]

For the gun death graph, I think it is hard to map each dot to year, a simple bar chart can visualize the given data without loss of any detail.

Comment: Please share what you have tried and where you feel it's failing. As this stands it's nothing more than "idea farming" and opinion based.

Comment: I have added a few thoughts, but I fear there may be something obvious I missed.